# Why am I getting different results for 'for' loop in python used list and a object to iterate through?

Tags: python-3.6

When I used for loop to iterate object

```
arr = map(int, input().split())

for j in arr: # this print's results
    print(j)

for i in arr: # this doesn't print any results
    print(i)
```

On the other hand

```
any = [5,8,6,4]

for i in any:  # this print's results
    print(i)

for j in any: # this also print's results
    print(j)
```

Why for iterating the object file it doesn't prints result for the second time. Can any one help?

Comment: What is the type of arr in the first case? If it is an iterator you can only iterate over it once. In the second case it is a list that has an `__iter__` method, so you can iterate over it repeatedly. Try wrapping map in list

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Python 3 documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), map() returns an iterator.  You can only consume iterator once.

See similar question [Python - Printing Map Object Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157057/python-printing-map-object-issue)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely in this case that input().split() is a generator object. 
Generator objects can only be used once. Using the example generator function from [this stackover flow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032155/why-can-a-python-generator-only-be-used-once) we can reproduce your issue

```
# Create generator function
def generator(n):
  a = 1

  for _ in range(n):
    yield a
    a += 1

# Set vars
a = [1 ,2, 3, 4]
b = generator(4)

## type(a) ->  list
## type(b) -> generator

# Print each var

# First time through list a
for i in a:
  print(i)
## prints 1, 2, 3, 4

# First time through list b
for i in b:
  print(i)
## prints 1, 2, 3, 4

# Second time through list a
for i in a:
  print(i)
## prints 1, 2, 3, 4

# Second time through list b
for i in b:
  print(i)

# Prints nothing
```

You may be able to fix this by converting `input().split()` into a list.
i.e
`list(input().split())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is the reason behind it, i guess it might be related to `iterators`, i've had this problem for a long time, one of the solutions i use most of the time is to convert the result of `map` to `list`, like :

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for j in arr: # this will print the results
    print(j)

for i in arr: # this also will print the results
    print(i)
```